# non-finite clause as a subject

Tags: gerunds, subjects, participles

This is [an excerpt from a 2010 book titled "Do Fish Feel Pain?"](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=aMvonPqzu_cC&pg=PT138&dq=when%20fish%20pens%20were%20constructed&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=when%20fish%20pens%20were%20constructed&f=false) by American biologist Victoria Braithwaite:

> During the early stages when the aquaculture industry was rapidly expanding, mistakes were made and these were costly both in terms of direct losses and in respect of the industry's image. High-density rearing led to outbreaks of infectious diseases that in some cases devastated not just the caged fish, but local wild fish populations too. The negative impact on local wildlife inhabiting areas close to the fish farms continues to be an ongoing public relations problem for the industry. **Furthermore, a general lack of knowledge and insufficient care being taken when fish pens or cages were initially constructed, meant that pollution from excess feed and fish waste created huge barren underwater deserts.**

In the last sentence, the subject is "a general lack of knowledge and insufficient care being taken when fish pens or cages were initially constructed" and the predicate is "meant that pollution from excess feed and fish waste created huge barren underwater deserts."

I think that the when-clause "when fish pens or cages were initially constructed" modifies "insufficient care being taken". So if we just forget about the when-clause for a moment, we have this subject:

> a general lack of knowledge and insufficient care being taken

So the subject comprises two elements combined with "and", the first element being "a general lack of knowledge" and the second being "insufficient care being taken".

Now, which of the following does this second element mean?

> (a) insufficient care that was taken

or

> (b) the fact that insufficient care was taken

Comment: The word **insufficient** renders the first paraphrase semantically impossible.  Consider: "the insufficient food that was eaten".   That would be an odd way to say that there was not enough food to eat. With a lack of food, we do not (cannot) eat the lacking food  *the not enough food that was eaten.  *The too few nails that they used made the structure rickety.

Answer (score 1):

I incline toward your b) paraphrase, "the fact that insufficient care was taken".

> ... insufficient care being taken when fish pens or cages were initially constructed ...

The passive gerund *being taken* is the head of this clause; *insufficient care* is its subject argument and the *when* clause is its adverbial modifier. It might be paraphrased "the taking of insufficient care when ...".

If Prof. Braithwaite had intended your paraphrase a), "insufficient care which was taken", with *being taken* as a participial modifier, she would presumably have written this without the superfluous *BE*: *and insufficient care taken when...*.

Comment: Thanks. Is the reason why the "be" would be superfluous because "being taken" would encode the superfluous progressive aspect?

Comment: No; it's superfluous because *wh- BE* is an unnecessary amplification of the bare passive participle. (Many linguists say that *wh- BE* is the underlying form, and the bare participle is a reduced relative clause, the product of *Whiz deletion*; but I think this is perverse.)

Comment: What is "wh- BE"?

Comment: Also, if there were a third reading, (c) _insufficient care that was **being** taken_, and that third reading were intended by the author, wouldn't the "being taken" in the original text encode the progressive aspect?

Comment: *wh- BE* means "any relative" followed by any realization of the verb *BE*, so *who was*, *which is*, *that is being*, *which had been*, &c.